Error while using jsPDF( Error: Could not load dompurify: ReferenceError: dompurify is not defined) in Angular 14 application
I am using jsPDF for angular and created custom config file and added this code,
module.exports = {
    // ...
    externals: {
      canvg: "canvg",
      html2canvas: "html2canvas",
      dompurify: "dompurify"
    }
  };

The app runs using ng build --watch.
I have tried many options but it still gives me an error: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Could not load dompurify: ReferenceError: dompurify is not defined
Error: Could not load dompurify: ReferenceError: dompurify is not defined
Is there any workround for this? Any suggestions will be helpful.

Can you just do an npm update in your project and retry?

I tried but it's still not working

Well in that case, delete your node_modules and the do npm install again

Tried, but still don't work, any other suggestion?

Check if your angular.json has below configuration:
{
"projects": {
"your-project-name": {
"architect": {
"build": {
"options": {
"scripts": [
"node_modules/canvg/dist/browser/canvg.min.js",
"node_modules/html2canvas/dist/html2canvas.min.js",
"node_modules/dompurify/dist/purify.min.js"
]
}
}
}
}
}
}

Also, in you webpack file:
odule.exports = {
// ...
externals: {
canvg: 'canvg',
html2canvas: 'html2canvas',
dompurify: 'dompurify'
},
plugins: [
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
canvg: 'canvg',
html2canvas: 'html2canvas',
dompurify: 'dompurify'
})
]
};

Ensure that below lines are in polyfills.ts: window as any).canvg = require('canvg');
(window as any).html2canvas = require('html2canvas');
(window as any).dompurify = require('dompurify');

They are not, can you give details on how I should add them, I tried the code you shared and it's giving me error like, html2canvas is not defined
